Python Selenium execute from cronjob linux and shell script
I have a shell script that executes a python script through a cronjob.
If I run the shell script or python script it executes without any issues.
It only has issues when I execute it from a cronjob.
Shell Script
!/bin/bash


# Set environment variables
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
export DISPLAY=:0
#export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

#echo "Current Date and time: $(date)"
#echo "current directory: $(pwd)"

#Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

#export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
#export DISPLAY=:0  #:99

LOGFILE=/opt/runscript.log

echo "Script Started at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE

cd /home/carson/Documents/code/python/speech2txt

source /home/carson/Documents/code/python/speech2txt/venv/bin/activate
#source ./venv/bin/activate
#/usr/bin/python3 /home/carson/Documents/code/python/speech2txt/createAudio.py >> /opt>

#/usr/bin/python3 /home/carson/Documents/code/python/speech2txt/cronBrowser.py >> $LOG>

su - carson -c "/usr/bin/python3 /home/carson/Documents/code/python/speech2txt/cronBro>

#echo "exit status $?"
deactivate

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Script Success - $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
else
        echo "Script Failure - $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
fi

Crobjob
12 16 * * * carson /opt/run.sh

#08 22 * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/:/usr/sbin:/bin && DISPLAY=:0 && /opt/run.sh

##47 21 * * * export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) && export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin && /opt/run.sh >> /opt/runscript.log 2>&1






Your shebang is broken. Please add a valid shebang (#!/bin/bash) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

script in cronjob may run as different user, in different folder with different privileges - it may need to write some message in log file to see which code is executed and which has problem. I'm not sure if cronjob has access to display. it may need to run with option --headless or with Xvfb. Python has even module for Xvfb to run it from script.

sorry Cyrus it looks like it didnt copy the # in the front of my shebang lol. I did have it correct

Here is the answer to my problem
0 8-16 * * 1-5 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /usr/bin/python3 /home/code.script.py

I was able to cut out the Shell script and run it straight with python3.
I have to use XDG_RUNTIME_DIR env variable for pulseaudio so my cronjob could use that service.
I am also using Selenium headless because cronjob doesnt have access to display.
The only issue I seem to be having which should be super simple is while i run it from a cronjob my code cant write its output to a file. When I run it normally just with python it writes no problem.
Anyways that's a problem for another day!
Thank you Furas
